# Unable to install openssl-libs

Tags: centos, software-installation, openssl, .net

I'm trying to install `dotnet-sdk-2.1` but it's failing due to that fact that openssl-libs isn't found. I've tried manually installing it using yum, but to no avail.
[image]
[image]
yum repolist
[image: yum repolist]
[image: yum disable repos]

Comment: Have you checked for issues related to version conflicts? `openssl-libs` is probably already installed on your system. What is the output of `yum list openssl-libs`?

Comment: @fra-san No packages matching to list.

Comment: No listed packages, neither installed nor available, sounds like a problem with cache/mirrors. Have you tried `yum clean all`?

Comment: @fra-san Yup, Still not found.

Comment: `openssl-libs` does not appear to be packaged for CentOS 6, though it is available in CentOS 7.  Is `dotnet-sdk-2.1` compatible with CentOS 6?

Comment: @GracefulRestart, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Install the library by hand and then try again

```
yum install openssl-libs
```

To avoid problems disable all repos but **base** and try again

Also you can try to clean all yum cache before try again

Comment: which library? "No package openssl-libs available."

Comment: @DireDoesGames, please check my updated answer

Comment: This didn't help. The package still isn't found.

Comment: @DireDoesGames, you can try to change the base repo. What is the result of `yum repolist`? (add it to question, as text, not image)

Comment: I added it as an image, I didn't notice you asked not to add as text.

Comment: @DireDoesGames, second time: disable all repos but **base** and clear cache

Comment: @DireDoesGames, good practice in SE is to add it as text, not image

Comment: @DireDoesGames, copy MY command. You try to install OpenSS**H**, you need OpenSS**L**

Comment: Exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the installation documentation for `dotnet-sdk-2.1`](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/centos/sdk-2.1.403), I can only find references for installing on CentOS 7.

Though I did find that they provide a [CentOS 6 package repo](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/6/prod.repo).

You should first undo anything you have previously tried to solve this, then slightly alter the official instructions to attempt to install the CentOS/RHEL 6 version:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/6/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm
sudo yum update
sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `yum -y install openssl.x86_64` or https://gist.github.com/gorshkov-leonid/7459e31cedaf3c0c83f5ac004c539dac#file-centos-openssl can help